# Object manipulation: two entries to combined collection

Tags: javascript, object

What process would you take to convert an array of object, with 3 key/value pairs, into a combined array of object, containing all combinations of key/value pairs? ...array can be any size.

Example:

```
var input = [
  {keyA: "value1a", keyB: "value1b", keyC: "value1c"},
  [keyA: "value2a", keyB: "value2b", keyC: "value2c"}
];
```

Converts to:

```
var output = [
  {keyA: "value1a", keyB: "value1b", keyC: "value1c"},
  {keyA: "value1a", keyB: "value1b", keyC: "value2c"},
  {keyA: "value1a", keyB: "value2b", keyC: "value1c"},
  {keyA: "value1a", keyB: "value2b", keyC: "value2c"},

  {keyA: "value2a", keyB: "value1b", keyC: "value1c"},
  {keyA: "value2a", keyB: "value1b", keyC: "value2c"},
  {keyA: "value2a", keyB: "value2b", keyC: "value1c"},
  {keyA: "value2a", keyB: "value2b", keyC: "value2c"},

  // etc.
];
```

I'm not 100% sure on how to approach it, in terms of arrays, I know with 3 arrays I'd do 3 nested loops concat or push into a single array. However, with objects I'm drawing blanks. I could push each value from each property into their own array and iterate each with nested loops, but believe there is a better way.

at current, I to exactly as mentioned above.

```
let a = [];
let b = [];
let c = [];

inputs.forEach(input => {
  a.push(input.key1);
  b.push(input.key2);
  c.push(input.key3);
});

let output = [];
a.forEach(x => {
  b.forEach(y => {
    c.forEach(z => {
      let result = {};
      result.a = x;
      result.b = y;
      result.c = z;
      output.push(result);
    });
  });
});
```

But have to imagine there's a better approach that I just can't put my finger on.

Comment: Added current approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you.

```
var len=2;
var Arr=[];
for(var i=1;i<=len;i++)
{
  for(var j=1;j<=len;j++)
  {
    for(var k=1;k<=len;k++)
    {
        var obj={
      keyA:"value"+i+"a",
      keyB:"value"+j+"a", 
      keyC:"value"+k+"a"
      };
      Arr.push(obj);
    }
  }
}
console.log(Arr);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7h2cdfay/2/